# Changing date range into series of dates (wide to long)

Tags: r, date

I would like take something like the data below

```
data<- data.frame("Subject" = c("13434","14544", "14544", 
                             "22222","22222","22222"), 
                  "Period" = c("MAD", "MAD", "OSE", "MAD","OSE","OSE"), 
                  "Dose" = c(400, 800, 800, 400, 800, 1200), 
                  "Start" = as.Date(c('2017-04-18','2017-06-13'
                        ,"2018-09-27", "2017-06-06","2018-08-21","2018-12-12")), 
                  "End" = as.Date(c("2017-05-16","2017-07-11", "2019-02-09",
                      "2017-07-04", "2018-12-11","2019-02-05")))

 data
Subject Period Dose  Start   End 
 13434  MAD  400    2017-04-18  2017-05-16
 14544  MAD  800    2017-06-13  2017-07-11
 14544  OSE  800    2018-09-27  2019-02-09
 22222  MAD  400    2017-06-06  2017-07-04
 22222  OSE  800    2018-08-21  2018-12-11
 22222  OSE  1200   2018-12-12  2019-02-05
```

And transform it into something like the below, where each date in the range is given a row and the dose is additive by day in the range.  In an ideal world when the period changes the cumulative dose would continue from where the previous period ends.

```
Subject Period Sum_Dose   Day
 13434  MAD    400   2017-04-18
 13434  MAD    800   2017-04-19
 13434  MAD   1200   2017-04-20
 13434  MAD   1600   2017-04-21
 13434  MAD   2000   2017-04-22
 13434  MAD   2400   2017-04-23
 Etc.
```

for each subject at during a given period and dose.

Comment: Not clear how the `day` field is getting generated

Comment: Day is each date in the range between Start and End

Comment: Still not clear why for `Subject=13434`, `Day` starts from `2017-04-18` and ends at `2017-04-23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  group_by(Subject, Period, Dose) %>%
  summarize(Day = list(seq(Start, End, by = 'day'))) %>% 
  unnest(Day) %>%
  mutate(Dose = cumsum(Dose)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 392 x 4
   Subject Period  Dose Day       
   <fct>   <fct>  <dbl> <date>    
 1 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-18
 2 13434   MAD      800 2017-04-19
 3 13434   MAD     1200 2017-04-20
 4 13434   MAD     1600 2017-04-21
 5 13434   MAD     2000 2017-04-22
 6 13434   MAD     2400 2017-04-23
 7 13434   MAD     2800 2017-04-24
 8 13434   MAD     3200 2017-04-25
 9 13434   MAD     3600 2017-04-26
10 13434   MAD     4000 2017-04-27
# ... with 382 more rows
```

I assume that tuples `(Subject, Period, Dose)` are unique. If not you can add grouping by `Start` `End`.

And the 'ideal-world', might be approached this way:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Subject, Period, Dose) %>%
  summarize(Day = list(seq(Start, End, by = 'day'))) %>% 
  unnest(Day) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  arrange(Day) %>%
  mutate(Dose = cumsum(Dose)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If we add following line to code above:

```
... %>% filter(Day >= as.Date("2018-12-11"), Day <= as.Date("2018-12-12"), 
               Subject == "22222")
```

It will output:

```
  Subject Period   Dose Day       
  <fct>   <fct>   <dbl> <date>    
1 22222   OSE    102000 2018-12-11
2 22222   OSE    103200 2018-12-12
```

So it seems that it correctly calculates the `cumsum` (adding 1200, which is the next dose for the next period) for the periods which follows one aft another.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @utubun!  I ended up with this,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dose.long <- data %>% 
  gather(g, DAY, Start, End) %>% 
  select(-g) %>%
  group_by(Subject, Period, Dose) %>% arrange(Subject, DAY) %>% 
  filter(is.na(DAY) == F) %>% 
  # Create a list column that includes all grades between existing
  summarize(DAY = list(full_seq(DAY, 1))) %>%
  # unnest the list
  unnest() %>% ungroup()%>%
  group_by(Subject)%>%
  mutate(Sum_Dose = cumsum(Dose))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to

1. expand each row into a sequence of days between the given `Start` and `End` dates,
2. accumulate `Dose` for each `Subject` across all days.

Reshaping "*wide to long*", e.g., `gather()` or `melt()`, is not needed here (and points into the wrong direction, IMHO).

#### `dplyr` and `tidyr`

Here is an implementation using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. As `seq()` does not accept vector arguments, we need to group by each row and to `unnest()` the expanded days.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(rn = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(Day = list(seq(Start, End, "1 day"))) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  arrange(Subject, Day) %>% 
  group_by(Subject)%>%
  mutate(Sum_Dose = cumsum(Dose)) %>% 
  select(Subject, Period, Sum_Dose, Day)
```

Note that ordering by `Day` before calling `cumsum()` is just a pre-caution in case `dat` is not already ordered or in case of overlapping date ranges.

> ```
> # A tibble: 392 x 5
> # Groups:   Subject [3]
>    Subject Period  Dose DAY        Sum_Dose
>    <fct>   <fct>  <dbl> <date>        <dbl>
>  1 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-18      400
>  2 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-19      800
>  3 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-20     1200
>  4 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-21     1600
>  5 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-22     2000
>  6 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-23     2400
>  7 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-24     2800
>  8 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-25     3200
>  9 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-26     3600
> 10 13434   MAD      400 2017-04-27     4000
> # ... with 382 more rows
> ```

#### `data.table`

The `data.table` version implements the same approach but is less verbose as "unnesting" is done implicitely.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, rn := .I][
  , .(Subject, Period, Dose, Day = seq(Start, End, "1 day")), by = rn][
    order(Day), .(Period, Sum_Dose = cumsum(Dose), Day), keyby = Subject]
```

> ```
>      Subject Period Sum_Dose        Day
>   1:   13434    MAD      400 2017-04-18
>   2:   13434    MAD      800 2017-04-19
>   3:   13434    MAD     1200 2017-04-20
>   4:   13434    MAD     1600 2017-04-21
>   5:   13434    MAD     2000 2017-04-22
>  ---                                   
> 388:   14544    OSE   128800 2019-02-05
> 389:   14544    OSE   129600 2019-02-06
> 390:   14544    OSE   130400 2019-02-07
> 391:   14544    OSE   131200 2019-02-08
> 392:   14544    OSE   132000 2019-02-09
> ```